# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'send_keys' Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm relatively new to coding and python. I'm trying to automate logging into linkedin to send messages to my connections. I'm using selenium webdriver for this process. I haven't been able to log in yet with the automated process because I'm getting
the error: dict object has no attribute send_keys.

I know in this code 'username' is a dictionary type because I checked and the error is telling me it has no attribute 'send_keys', I get what the error message is saying, that the attribute does not exist, but I don't know how to fix it. I'd also like to ask the variable I've created called 'username' can I call that anything? I know calling it username is probably the best, but I'm asking this for my understanding.

The following code is what I have done so far, I know it's not complete but I like to work and fix issues one line at a time.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time 

s = Service("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get("https://linkedin.com/login")

time.sleep(2)

username = driver.find_element(By.ID,"username")
username.send_keys("my email address goes here")
```

I'm also attaching an image so it can be seen what part of the LinkedIn page and tags I'm using to try to log in.

[Linkedin inspect element code on signing page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIvVy.png)

I hope I haven't left anything out, I tried to be as descriptive as possible.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: instead of `driver.find_element` use, the name of the field i.e session_key as shown in your picture so do, `driver.find_element_by_name('session_key')`

Comment: I changed the line as you said, but I'm still getting the following error message: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'send_key'.  So this is for the username.send_keys line, when I enter my email address.

Answer (score 1):

#### This is a bug!

> The method `webdriver.find_element()` is supposed to return an object `webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement` and not a dictionary.

Hence, this behaviour is most likely a bug as documented [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/9978) and not a coding error of yours.

You might be using an **old version of chromium** in combination with the newer **selenium 4.0**.

#### How to fix it

##### Option A — Software Update.

Make sure you have the **latest version** installed for your **web browser**, **web driver** and **selenium**.

##### Option B — Code Patch.

*In case you can't update (I had the problem on my RaspberryPi, here I don't have the option to update Chromium since it is no longer supported.):*

You have to activate the w3c option for your webdriver.

```py
import time 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options       # [!]

s = Service("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
opts = Options()                                            # [!]
opts.add_experimental_option('w3c', True)                   # [!]
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=opts)          # [!]
driver.get("https://linkedin.com/login")

time.sleep(2)

username = driver.find_element(By.ID,"username")
username.send_keys("my email address goes here")
```